# find attribute in a rails model with another has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I really don't know how to bring up the question, so I going to explain it.

I have the next models: Movie, Genre and Theater. The movies and theaters have a many-to-many relationship. Movies and genres have the same relationship.

In rails:

- theaters `has_many` movies
- movies `belongs_to` theaters
- movies `has_many` genres
- genres `belongs_to` movies

**My problem:**

with `theater = Theater.all.first` (for example) I can get the first theater and then do `theater.movies` and get all the movies that the theater has. But how I can get only the movies with a specific genre? Must be some nice way to do it, but I din't find any.

Answer (score 0):

First of all what you describe "in rails", is not a many-to-many relation, but a one-to-many. Look up `has_and_belongs_to_many` or `has_many :through` relations. see [ActiveRecord Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-types-of-associations)

What you want, should be easy.
If you have `genre` available, than `a_genre.movies` will work.
Otherwise you'll need to start from `Movie` and construct your query:

```
Movie.joins(:genres).where({genres: { name: ['comedy', 'drama']}})
Movie.joins(:genres, :theaters).where({genres: { name: ['comedy', 'drama']}}).
  where({theaters: { city: 'NY' }})
```